# Javascript what does this line of code mean

Tags: javascript

Im learning Javascript, but do not know why this line is written this way.  Can someone help explain why javascript is writing code like this?

What does `cinnamon && (this.cinnamon = [1, "stick", "Saigon"])` mean?
I understand the first line above it.  The second line seems to be doing a comparison operator with &&, but does not assign it to any variable.

```
      var VanillaBean = function(vanilla, cinnamon) {
      this.vanilla = [1, "bean", vanilla ? vanilla : "Madagascar Bourbon"];
      cinnamon && (this.cinnamon = [1, "stick", "Saigon"]);  //?????
    };
    VanillaBean.prototype = {
      heavyCream: [1, "cup", "Organic Valley"],
      halfHalf: [2, "cup", "Organic Valley"],
      sugar: [5/8, "cup"],
      yolks: [6]
    };
    var vanilla = new VanillaBean("Tahitian", true);
    console.dir(vanilla);
```

Comment: Same as `if (cinnamon) this.cinnamon = [...]`

Comment: More precisly there is no need to execute the second member of the operation && if the first one is not true since both need to be true for the result to be true, which means that the second is execute if the first is true, as said above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The line:

```
cinnamon && (this.cinnamon = [1, "stick", "Saigon"]);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
if (cinnamon) {
    this.cinnamon = [1, "stick", "Saigon"];
}
```

The [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) nature of the logical `AND` operator is sometimes used this way, since the resulting code is shorter than a full `if` statement.

That said, I would personally discourage writing code like this, as it is less readable and maintainable than an `if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

The logical && operator is "lazy", it only evaluates the second expression if the first one is true. it is equivalent to `if(cinnamon){ this.cinnamon=[...];}`

Similarly `cinnamon || this.cinnamon=[...];` is equivalent to `if(!cinnamon){this.cinnamon=[...];}` because the when you evaluate an OR, you need to test (and therefore execute) the second expression only if the first one is false.It's best understood from the complements:

(false && anything)=false, so don't bother executing the second suite

(true || anything)=true, so don't bother executing the second suite